# Google-apps-script will not send email inside an onEdit function

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a script that sends an email when the spreadsheet is edited. The script runs, but the MailApp statement does not work.

Here is the execution log:

> [15-01-27 14:15:17:951 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:951 EST] Spreadsheet.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:952 EST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:952 EST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:952 EST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:952 EST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:955 EST] Starting execution
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:969 EST] Logger.log([{"range":{"rowStart":79,"rowEnd":79,"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":6},"source":{},"value":"Xxxx","user":{}},
>   []]) [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:17:969 EST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:058 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.088 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:145 EST] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.086 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:145 EST] Logger.log([Customer row = 79, []]) [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:145 EST] Sheet.getRange([79, 6]) [0 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:233 EST] Sheet.getDataRange() [0.087 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:324 EST] Range.getValues() [0.091 seconds]
>   [15-01-27 14:15:18:327 EST] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call sendEmail (line 21, file "Code") [0.368 seconds
>   total runtime]

I have used the mailApp.sendEmail on other scripts and it works well. This is the second script attached to the spreadsheet/form, the first also sends an email from formSubmit. I have allowed all triggers and permissions.

Any help appreciated
code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[4];       

  var column = Number(e.range.columnStart);

  if(column != 6){return};
  var Customer = Number(e.range.rowStart);
  Logger.log('Customer row = '+Customer);

  var name = sheet1.getRange(Customer,6);
  var emailArray = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i=0;i < emailArray.length;i++){

    if (name == emailArray[i][0]) { 
     var email_address = emailArray[i][1];
    }
  }                 

  var subject = "Job assignment";
  var body    = "X";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address,subject,body);
}
```

Comment: The script does run, but not completely.  It fails on line 21.  The error states that it's a permissions problem calling a `sendEmail` function.  Is the `sendEmail` function in the same project?  We need to see some code.

Comment: Code added above, not sure why some is in code format and the rest is not, sorry

Comment: as a complement to below answers, read the doc about simple trigger restrictions here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: Thanks everyone, I now have another fault, where I am getting and undefined error in the email. It seems the     var name = sheet1.getRange(Customer,6); isn't picking up the value to feed the array?

Comment: Ok, thanks to all who have helped. I have solved the second problem using `sheet1.getSheetValues(Customerrow,2,1,1);` to pick the correct values and feed the array and email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling sendMail inside the onEdit() trigger. You cannot call URLFetch or MailApp methods inside onEdit.

Answer (score 14):

Like the other answer says you cant call sendMail from the normal onEdit.
**To fix**: rename onEdit to something else like "onEditTrigger" and [manually install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) the trigger from the "Resources" menu.
That link also explains the difference, including the restriction you just found out, between the different types of triggers. In this case, onEdit is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) while my onEditTrigger is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: This worked well for me. I wonder if installable triggers are copied over if you programmatically duplicate a spreadsheet file?

Comment: seems easy to try :) I doubt they are copied.