# Add Gmail Sending Permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gmail, google-oauth

I was trying to send an email based on `onEdit()` trigger. But getting these exceptions. It's not asking me for any permission. Where can I add those **gmail.send** and **gmail.compose** permissions?

> Aug 14, 2020, 9:29:23 PM  Error   Exception: The script does not have
> permission to perform that action. Required permissions:
> (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send ||
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose ||
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify ||
> https://mail.google.com/ ||
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose)
> at emailSender(Code:54:13)
> at onEdit(Code:70:6)

If I run the following function it sends email to my desired mail address using the same script.

```js
function testEmail(){
  GmailApp.sendEmail("shahrearbinamin1@gmail.com",
                      "Price Changed",
                     "test");
}
```

But the following email sending function does not work end up with the previous error.

```
function emailSender(website,name, price){
   GmailApp.sendEmail("shahrearbinamin1@gmail.com",
                      "Price Changed",
                      website+"'s "+name+" New Price : "+price);
}

function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  if(currentSheetName==="Coles"){
    if(column===5)
    {
     var name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2);
     emailSender("Coles",name,e.value);
     
    }
  }
  else if(currentSheetName==="Woolworths"){
     if(column===6 && e.oldValue.length!==0){
        var name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2);
        emailSender("Woolworths",name,e.value);
     }
  }
   
}
```

Here I've found permission under **File->Project Properties**. Tried to add permission here **Script Properties** tab. But it's not adding along with following permission.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple triggers are not able to send emails. Use an installable trigger.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Related

- [Google-apps-script will not send email inside an onEdit function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163274/1595451)
- [Sending an Email on Dropdown Change, GAS won't Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62560458/1595451)