# Function executed if run manually but not on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following function actually sends me an email if I run it manually from the Script Editor:

```
function sendMail(){
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");
 var data = sh.getRange("A1:C20").getValues();
  //var htmltable =[];

var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

htmltable += '<tr>';

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

     htmltable += '</tr>';
}

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Your latest vocabulary','' ,{htmlBody: htmltable})
}
```

However, it does not send me an email if I execute it via the onEdit function and actually perform an edit on the spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  sendMail();
}
```

Could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: If you are using `onEdit` as the simple trigger, unfortunately, the simple trigger cannot use the method of `MailApp.sendEmail`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) In this case, please use the installable OnEdit trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) At that time, please rename `onEdit` to other name like `installedOnEdit` for avoising the duplicate executing the function of `onEdit`. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

Comment: I thought that this thread might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163274

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163274 .